# How to disable a specific input field in ngFor based on another field value

Tags: javascript, angular

Sorry if this is a stupid questions, I am new to Angular. I did a search on this, but couldn't find a similar question. Please let me know if this is duplicated.

I have a data set like the following

```
    {{country: "Canada";
      city: "Toronto";
      weather: {
      {date: "06JUL2018"
          temp: 26;
          rain: "3mm";},
      {date: "07JUL2018"
          temp: 24;
          rain: "0mm";}
      {date: "08JUL2018"
          temp: 28;
          rain: "0mm";}......}
    },
    {country: "Canada";
      city: "Vancouvr";
      weather: {
      {date: "06JUL2018"
          temp: 31;
          rain: "0mm";},
      {date: "07JUL2018"
          temp: 23;
          rain: "0mm";}
      {date: "08JUL2018"
          temp: 21;
          rain: "0mm";}......}
    },........
    }
```

in my html i have

```
    <form *ngFor='let data of dataList'>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>{{ data.country }} - {{data.city}} </legend>
        <ng-container *ngFor='let wDetails of data.weather' >
          <label >{{ wDetails.date }}:</label>  
          <select name={{wDetails.rain}} value={{wDetails.rain}} (ngModel)="flag">
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
          <input type="text" name={{wDetails.volume}} value={{wDetails.volume}} [disabled]="flag">
        </ng-container>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
```

I made some changes to the data and code to hide sensitive information from work, but the idea is the same.

What i am trying to do is have the **wDetails.volume** input field disabled based on the **wDetails.rain** field value for that city. If the user change **wDetails.rain**  from 'yes' to 'no' for Toronto, then the **wDetails.volume** for Toronto should be disabled, and Vancouver one should still be enable.

When i do it in my way, the value **wDetails.rain** become empty on the page, and when i change it, it disable ALL the **wDetails.volume** input field.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't get what is `busDefConfig`, I hope it doesn't matter in this case

And here is the solution

```
<form *ngFor='let data of dataList'>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>{{ data.country }} - {{data.city}} </legend>
        <ng-container *ngFor='let wDetails of data.weather' >
          <label >{{ wDetails.date }}:</label>  
          <select [name]="busDefConfig.type" [(ngModel)]="wDetails.showVolume">
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
          <input type="text" [name]="wDetails.volume" [value]="wDetails.volume" [disabled]="!wDetails.showVolume">
        </ng-container>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Your problem was binding this logic to global variable `flag`. You just need to bind it to something local, which is related to `wDetails` object, so the changes will affect only elements which are using this particular object. I used `wDetails.showVolume` in this case

And also you can bind html element properties by wrapping it into `[]` and not to use `{{}}` in html element attributes

Comment: wouldn't my select field become empty because 'value={{wDetails.rain}}' is removed from it? and if i use both value={{wDetails.rain}}' and '[(ngModel)]="wDetails.showVolume"' the value is not showing. 

I will try it later today, but i remembered that's what happened when i was experimenting

Comment: `value` is not a valid attribute for <select> tag. Data is bound to this element via `[(ngModel)]`

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-container *ngFor='let wDetails of data.weather' >
      <label >{{ wDetails.date }}:</label>  
      <select name={{busDefConfig.type}} value={{busDefConfig.value}} (ngModel)="flag">
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" name={{wDetails.volume}} value={{wDetails.volume}} [disabled]="flag">
 </ng-container>
```

I suspect that your `ngModel` should be `wDetails.flag` instead of `flag`, so that it is specific to that set of weather details.